# Absolute difference for proving continuity

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

A function $|f|:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $|f|(x)=|f(x)|$ for $x$ in $D$.  Prove it is continuous if $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

In my professor's solution to this proof he writes:

$||f(x_{n})|-|f(x_{0})||\leq|f(x_{n})-f(x_{0})|$

Where does this inequality come from?

Comment: If $f(x_n)$ and $f(x_0)$ have same sign, equality holds. Consider case that they have opposite sign.

Comment: @Jinyong Go: ||−8|−|3||<|-8−3| and so 5<11 and ||8|−|3||=|8−3| since 5=5. Thanks. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the the reverse triangle inequality. The following is a proof: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality

Comment: Great, I appreciate that info.  Thanks!  My professor usually sites when he uses that...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. Recall the triangle inequality 
$$\vert x-y\vert \leq \vert x  \vert+\vert y \vert$$
Now apply this inequality to both $\vert x \vert =\vert(x-y)+y \vert$ and $\vert y \vert=\vert (y-x)+x \vert$. Try to deduce that $$\vert \vert x \vert-\vert y \vert \vert\leq \vert x-y\vert$$

Use this inequality to show that the absolute value is continuous. composition of continuous functions is continuous, this will imply $\vert f \vert$ is continuous.